# How do I identify Xpath when there are multiple elements with the same attributes and text?

Tags: html, xml, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I need to click on the link that says "Customer One". Currently I am using

```
//div[contains(@class,'client-info') and contains(div/text(),'Customer')]
```

Using Firepath, this returns four seperate elements (I have attached code that includes two of them), and I think that is why Selenium Webdriver is unable to find the element I would like to click.

I Need to click the very last instance of this xpath, but it doesn't appear possible to be any more specific, as they have the same class and inner text!

```
<div class="wg-client-row-mobile hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-11">
<span class="icon icon-user" ng-class="{'icon-user': !wgClientItemCtrl.client.isAnOrganization, 'icon-business': wgClientItemCtrl.client.isAnOrganization}"/>
<div class="client-info">
<div class="client-name not-long-text ng-binding">Customer One</div>
<!-- <div class="client-age not-long-text" ng-if="!wgClientItemCtrl.client.isAnOrganization">{{wgClientItemCtrl.client.gender}}, {{wgClientItemCtrl.client.calculatedAge | notAvailable}}</div> -->
<!-- ngIf: !wgClientItemCtrl.client.isAnOrganization -->
<div class="client-age not-long-text ng-binding ng-scope" ng-if="!wgClientItemCtrl.client.isAnOrganization">
<!-- end ngIf: !wgClientItemCtrl.client.isAnOrganization -->
<!-- ngIf: wgClientItemCtrl.client.isAnOrganization -->
<div class="client-age not-long-text ng-binding">
</div>
</div>
<div class="favorite-right-container">
</div>
</div>
<div class="wg-client-row-desktop hidden-xs hidden-is">
<div class="row content">
<div class="col-sm-4">
<div class="icon icon-user" ng-class="{'icon-user': !wgClientItemCtrl.client.isAnOrganization, 'icon-business': wgClientItemCtrl.client.isAnOrganization}"/>
<div class="client-info">
<div class="client-name not-long-text ng-binding">Customer One</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `last()` to get the last instance matched by the inner XPath :

```
(//div[contains(@class,'client-info') and contains(div/text(),'Customer')])[last()]
```

Comment: One match found according to Xpath checker. Thanks! To avoid future headaches, what if it's not THE last? is there something like third()?